# Using Cost Sensitive C50 in caret

Tags: r, r-caret

I am using train in caret package to train some c50 models. I manage to do fine with the method C5.0 but when I want to use the cost sensitive C50 method I struggle understanding how to tune the cost parameter. What I am trying to do is to introduce a cost when predicting wrong one of my classes. I've try searching in the caret package website (http://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html) and reading several manuals/tutorials found here and there. I didn't find any information about how to handle the cost parameter. So this is what I tried on my own:

1. Run the train with the default settings to see what I get. In the output, the train function tried with cost from 0 to 2 and gave the best model for cost=2.
2. Try to add in the expand.grid function the cost as a matrix, the same way you'd do using the package C5.0. The code is below (trials is pushed to 1 cause I just want one tree/set of rules in my output)

   c50Grid <- expand.grid(.trials=1, .model=c("tree", "rules"), .winnow=c("TRUE", "FALSE"), .cost=matrix(c(0,1,2,0), ncol=2))

However when I execute the train function, although I don't get any errors (but I get 50 warnings), the train tried again cost from 0 to 2. What am I doing wrong? Which format has the cost parameter? What's the meaning here? How would I interpret the results? Which class is the one getting the cost as "Predicting class 0 wrong cost double than class 1"? Also, what I tried was using one matrix, but although it didn't work with this format, how would I add the different costs that I want to test?

Thanks! Any help would be really welcome!

---

Edit:

So, trying to find an answer on my own about the meaning of the cost parameter for the C5.0Cost, I went to the C5.0Cost.R (https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/models/files/C5.0Cost.R?view=markup&root=caret&pathrev=761) and looked up the code. 
This line:

```
cmat <-matrix(c(0, param$cost, 1, 0), ncol = 2)
```

I guess, it's passing the cost parameter to the cost matrix. So, I think now I can understand how it works. If I have class = {0,1} and my positive class is 0, this matrix says that "Predicting class 0 wrong costs double than class 1", right?
My question now is, how could I do the opposite? How could I set that "Predicting class 1 wrong costs double than class 0", which would be:

```
cmat <- matrix(c(0, 1, param$cost, 0), ncol=2)
```

Could I just set the cost to 0.5? And if want to train with different values, just use values less than 1 { 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, etc}.
Note: the way my data is, when I used C50 or other trees before, it takes as "Positive class = 0", so I had to invert the cost matrix when I used C50 so if I use caret method C5.0Cost, I'd need to do the same or find another way to do it...

I'd really appreciate any help here. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

There is a cost-senstivite model code for `train` and C5.0 (use `method = "C5.0Cost"`). For example:

```
library(caret)

set.seed(1)
dat1 <- twoClassSim(1000, intercept = -12)
dat2 <- twoClassSim(1000, intercept = -12)

stats <- function (data, lev = NULL, model = NULL)  {
  c(postResample(data[, "pred"], data[, "obs"]),
    Sens = sensitivity(data[, "pred"], data[, "obs"]),
    Spec = specificity(data[, "pred"], data[, "obs"]))
}

ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", repeats = 5,
                     summaryFunction = stats)

set.seed(2)
mod1 <- train(Class ~ ., data = dat1, 
              method = "C5.0",
              tuneGrid = expand.grid(model = "tree", winnow = FALSE,
                                     trials = c(1:10, (1:5)*10)),
              trControl = ctrl)

xyplot(Sens + Spec ~ trials, data = mod1$results, 
       type = "l",
       auto.key = list(columns = 2, 
                       lines = TRUE, 
                       points = FALSE))

set.seed(2)
mod2 <- train(Class ~ ., data = dat1, 
              method = "C5.0Cost",
              tuneGrid = expand.grid(model = "tree", winnow = FALSE,
                                     trials = c(1:10, (1:5)*10),
                                     cost = 1:10),
              trControl = ctrl)

xyplot(Sens + Spec ~ trials|format(cost), data = mod2$results, 
       type = "l",
       auto.key = list(columns = 2, 
                       lines = TRUE, 
                       points = FALSE))
```

Max

Comment: Thanks Max. As I indicated above, I've tried to use the method you say but I struggle understanding the meaning of cost there and how to work with it. I can see now that it is indicated as an integer. But what does it mean? When I've use cost-sensitive C50 using the C50 package in R, I put the cost as a matrix and I find that easy to understand as for which class I am setting a misclassification cost. But using just a number, to which class am I adding that misclassification cost? Or does it have a different meaning?

Comment: The answer by @smithDe on this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32055176/how-to-change-the-cost-matrix-in-r-with-caret-and-c5-0cost  explains how to determine the relationship between the Caret cost to the C50.0 cost matrix; i.e. code for cmat in https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/models/files/C5.0Cost.R is matrix(c(0, param$cost, 1, 0), ncol = 2) and https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/C50/C50.pdf states rows are predicted classes.  Therefore caret cost with value 5 indicates the cost of predicting class 1 as class 2 is five times the usual value (of one).

Answer (score 1):

> If I have class = {0,1} and my positive class is 0, this matrix says that  "Predicting class 0 wrong costs double than class 1", right? My question now is, how could I do the opposite? How could I set that "Predicting class 1 wrong costs double than class 0" [...]?

Unfortunately, you can't change the costs for the false positives in caret at the moment. This appears to be a bug! See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32055176/how-to-change-the-cost-matrix-in-r-with-caret-and-c5-0cost) for further information about this issue.