# How to change the cost matrix in R with caret and C5.0Cost?

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm currently experimenting with caret and C5.0Cost in R. So far I have a base model that is working fine. But the *tuning parameters* give me some headaches.

I seem to be unable to change the cost for the false positives.

```
library(mlbench)
data(Sonar)

library(caret)

set.seed(990)
inTraining <- createDataPartition(Sonar$Class, p = .5, list = FALSE)
inTraining
training <- Sonar[inTraining,]
test <- Sonar[-inTraining,]

set.seed(990)
fitControl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=5)
statGrid <-  expand.grid(trials = 1,
                     model = "tree",
                     winnow = FALSE,
                     cost = matrix(c(
                         0, 2,
                         1, 0
                     ), 2, 2, byrow=TRUE))

set.seed(825)
statFit <- train(Class~., data=training, method="C5.0Cost", trControl=fitControl, tuneGrid = statGrid, metric = "Accuracy")

statFit["finalModel"]

write(capture.output(summary(statFit)), "c50model.txt")
```

> R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
>   Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)
>
> locale:
>   [1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252     LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252
>   [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252
>
> attached base packages:
>   [1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:
>   [1] DMwR_0.4.1      plyr_1.8.3      C50_0.1.0-24    caret_6.0-52     ggplot2_1.0.1   lattice_0.20-31
>   [7] mlbench_2.1-1
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
>   [1] Rcpp_0.11.6         compiler_3.2.1      nloptr_1.0.4        bitops_1.0-6
>   [5] xts_0.9-7           class_7.3-12        iterators_1.0.7     tools_3.2.1
>   [9] rpart_4.1-9         partykit_1.0-3      digest_0.6.8        lme4_1.1-8
>   [13] nlme_3.1-120        gtable_0.1.2        mgcv_1.8-6          Matrix_1.2-1
>   [17] foreach_1.4.2       parallel_3.2.1      brglm_0.5-9         SparseM_1.6
>   [21] proto_0.3-10        e1071_1.6-7         BradleyTerry2_1.0-6 stringr_1.0.0
>   [25] caTools_1.17.1      gtools_3.5.0        stats4_3.2.1        nnet_7.3-9
>   [29] survival_2.38-1     gdata_2.17.0        minqa_1.2.4         ROCR_1.0-7
>   [33] TTR_0.23-0          reshape2_1.4.1      car_2.0-26          magrittr_1.5
>   [37] gplots_2.17.0       scales_0.2.5        codetools_0.2-11    MASS_7.3-40
>   [41] splines_3.2.1       quantmod_0.4-5      abind_1.4-3         pbkrtest_0.4-2
>   [45] colorspace_1.2-6    quantreg_5.11       KernSmooth_2.23-14  stringi_0.5-5
>   [49] munsell_0.4.2       zoo_1.7-12

The only change that is accepted by caret (?) is a change to the false negatives (the one in the example above that is set to two). All other changes are ignored, unfortunately. One can easily confirm this by typing `statFit["finalModel"]` to the R-console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JimBoy I was running into the same issue as you. I took look at the source code on github for the caret wrapper for the ["C5.0Cost"](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/models/files/C5.0Cost.R) you can see that the the upper left of the matrix is set to 1 in the code (see the cmat object).

I modified cost input in modelInfo so that you can add costs to both flase positives and negatives. Instead of including one cost parameter you now have two to specify in the grid.expand false positives (costFP) and false negative (costFN), which are a vector of the costs you want to assess.

```
modelInfo <- list(label = "Cost-Sensitive C5.0",
            library = c("C50", "plyr"),
            loop = function(grid) {     
              loop <- ddply(grid, c("model", "winnow", "costFP","costFN"),
                            function(x) c(trials = max(x$trials)))                 

              submodels <- vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(loop))
              for(i in seq(along = loop$trials))
              {
                index <- which(grid$model == loop$model[i] & 
                                 grid$winnow == loop$winnow[i],
                               grid$costFP[i] == loop$costFP[i],
                               grid$costFN[i] == loop$costFN[i])
                trials <- grid[index, "trials"] 
                submodels[[i]] <- data.frame(trials = trials[trials != loop$trials[i]])
              }     
              list(loop = loop, submodels = submodels)
            },
            type = "Classification",
            parameters = data.frame(parameter = c('trials', 'model', 'winnow', "costFP","costFN"),
                                    class = c("numeric", "character", "logical", "numeric","numeric"),
                                    label = c('# Boosting Iterations', 'Model Type', 'Winnow', "CostFP","CostFN")),
            grid = function(x, y, len = NULL, search = "grid") {
              c5seq <- if(len == 1)  1 else  c(1, 10*((2:min(len, 11)) - 1))
              expand.grid(trials = c5seq, model = c("tree", "rules"), 
                          winnow = c(TRUE, FALSE),
                          costFP = 1:2,
                          costFN = 1:2)
              if(search == "grid") {
                c5seq <- if(len == 1)  1 else  c(1, 10*((2:min(len, 11)) - 1))
                out <- expand.grid(trials = c5seq, model = c("tree", "rules"), 
                                   winnow = c(TRUE, FALSE), costFP = 1:2, costFN = 1:2)
              } else {
                out <- data.frame(trials = sample(1:100, replace = TRUE, size = len),
                                  model = sample(c("tree", "rules"), replace = TRUE, size = len),
                                  winnow = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), replace = TRUE, size = len),
                                  costFP = runif(len, min = 1, max = 20),
                                  costFN = runif(len, min = 1, max = 20))
              }
              out    
            },
            fit = function(x, y, wts, param, lev, last, classProbs, ...) { 
              theDots <- list(...)

              if(any(names(theDots) == "control"))
              {                           
                theDots$control$winnow <- param$winnow
              } else theDots$control <- C5.0Control(winnow = param$winnow)

              argList <- list(x = x, y = y, weights = wts, trials = param$trials,
                              rules = param$model == "rules")

              cmat <-matrix(c(0, param$costFP, param$costFN, 0), ncol = 2)
              rownames(cmat) <- colnames(cmat) <- levels(y)
              if(any(names(theDots) == "costFP")){
                warning("For 'C5.0Cost', the costs are a tuning parameter")
                theDots$costs <- cmat
              } else argList$costs <- cmat

              argList <- c(argList, theDots)
              do.call("C5.0.default", argList)
            },
            predict = function(modelFit, newdata, submodels = NULL) {
              out <- predict(modelFit, newdata)

              if(!is.null(submodels))
              {
                tmp <- out
                out <- vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(submodels) + 1)
                out[[1]] <- tmp

                for(j in seq(along = submodels$trials))
                  out[[j+1]] <- as.character(predict(modelFit, newdata, trial = submodels$trials[j]))
              }
              out              
            },
            prob = NULL,
            predictors = function(x, ...) {
              vars <- C5imp(x, metric = "splits")
              rownames(vars)[vars$Overall > 0]
            },
            levels = function(x) x$obsLevels,
            varImp = function(object, ...) C5imp(object, ...),
            tags = c("Tree-Based Model", "Rule-Based Model", "Implicit Feature Selection",
                     "Boosting", "Ensemble Model", "Cost Sensitive Learning", "Two Class Only", 
                     "Handle Missing Predictor Data", "Accepts Case Weights"),
            sort = function(x){
              x$model <- factor(as.character(x$model), levels = c("rules", "tree"))
              x[order(x$trials, x$model, !x$winnow, x$costFP,x$costFN),]
            },
            trim = function(x) {
              x$boostResults <- NULL
              x$size <- NULL
              x$call <- NULL
              x$output <- NULL
              x
            })
```

The example you provided above can the be run as follows,

```
## Example provided
library(mlbench)
data(Sonar)

library(caret)


set.seed(990)
inTraining <- createDataPartition(Sonar$Class, p = .5, list = FALSE)
inTraining
training <- Sonar[inTraining,]
test <- Sonar[-inTraining,]



set.seed(990)
fitControl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=5)


statGrid <-  expand.grid(trials = 3,
                         model = "tree",
                         winnow = FALSE,
                         cost = 2)

set.seed(825)


statFit <- train(Class~., data=training, method="C5.0Cost", trControl=fitControl, tuneGrid = statGrid, metric = "Accuracy")


## Example modified to include costs for both false positives and negatives
set.seed(825)
statGridMod <-  expand.grid(trials = 3,
                            model = "tree",
                            winnow = FALSE,
                            costFP = c(1,2,3), #new cost parameters
                            costFN = c(3,2,1)) #new cost parameters


statFit <- train(Class~., data=training, method=modelInfo, trControl=fitControl, tuneGrid = statGridMod, metric = "Accuracy")

statFit
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :) In the meantime I switched to mlr, though. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Page 3 of the [C5.0 documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/C50/C50.pdf) provides detail on implementing the cost matrix. From the documentation, you can see that "diagonal elements [of the cost matrix] are ignored"

Comment: Thank you, Tchotchke! Unfortunately, this doesn't solve my problem. Regardless of what element of the matrix I change, the only visible change resolves to the false negatives.

Comment: Providing a reproducible example and the results of `sessionInfo` will help get your question answered.

Comment: @topepo Thank you, Max! :) I've added a reproducible example to my question above that shows the odd behavior.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. When I change the cost matrix above to all 3s, the only change I'm seeing is to the FN. The FP stays at 1, and the diagonal are at 0 (as they should be)

Comment: @topepo This seems to be an issue in caret. A native implementation of the algorithm above in C50 works just fine.